# WCF CPU usage increase by 25% for each client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

As the title says, i got a WCF Server having this service behavior defined:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

I' using a named pipe binding and my clients are connecting in this way:

```
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
const int maxValue = 0x40000000; // 1GB
binding.MaxBufferSize = maxValue; 
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxValue;

binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = maxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = maxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = maxValue;

// receive timeout acts like a general timeout
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

ChannelFactory<IDatabaseSession> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDatabaseSession>(binding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/DatabaseService"));

IDatabaseSession dbSession = pipeFactory.CreateChannel()
```

Every client I start executes the code above, and for every client the CPU usage raises by 25% (actually not for the 5. client, but at this point the service execteable is covering nearly a 100% of the whole CPU capacity).

What I'm searching for is a kind of resource (website/list or just YOUR powerful knowledge) telling me what a CreateChannel actually does (regarding in resource allocation issues).

hint: the CPU usage increases even if no communication is actually done, just the Channel is created.

Comment: I predict you have 4 cores and something spinning in a tight loop.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger and/or CPU profiler.

Comment: actually you're right tzerb. 4 cores and some, not found so far, tiny loop ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that WCF itself is using that much resources especially since you said this happens even when there is no communication. My guess is that it is a problem with the service and not the clients. Look at the service constructor if you have one. Also experiment with different values of `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode`.

Comment: it was a problem with the dll managed by my service ... actually no client problem.

Answer (score 3):

Pause the debugger and see where all threads have halted. This is likely the hot part of your code. Look at the call stack.